# Dynamically creating a schema in Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Is it possible to create a Realm schema programatically without pre-defining it in a file? In other words, am I able to create object schemas dynamically during run time?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Check the StackOverflow's help on asking questions first, please. Focus on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but also other [help topics](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) would be useful.

Comment: I'd suggest asking this on [Realm's GitHub page](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues). You'll likely get your question closed here without showing what you've tried already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's technically possible at the Objective-C runtime level to dynamically generate Realm object subclasses with properties determined at runtime, and to subsequently add them as a new model object to a Realm file.

That being said, it's not an officially supported way of using Realm, and would require a fair amount of boilerplate code. If you can, I would recommend re-thinking your architecture to see if it's possible to achieve what you're aiming to do another way.

Sandy Chapman is right in that this question may be a little too broad for Stack Overflow and it might be better off as a new issue on [the Realm-Cocoa GitHub repo](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues).